# OOM Exception in my spark streaming application

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using Spark 1.4.1 on a HDP 2.3.2.0 cluster and i have a simple application that create a dstream that read data from Kafka and apply a filter transformation on it. This application is launched using as master *yarn-client*. After more or less a day throw the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.spark.util.io.ByteArrayChunkOutputStream.allocateNewChunkIfNeeded(ByteArrayChunkOutputStream.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.util.io.ByteArrayChunkOutputStream.write(ByteArrayChunkOutputStream.scala:55)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.dumpOutput(SnappyOutputStream.java:294)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.flush(SnappyOutputStream.java:273)
at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.close(SnappyOutputStream.java:324)
at org.apache.spark.io.SnappyOutputStreamWrapper.close(CompressionCodec.scala:203)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.close(Output.java:168)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.close(KryoSerializer.scala:162)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:203)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1291)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:874)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:815)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1426)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
[Stage 53513:>                                                      (0 + 0) / 4]Exception in thread "JobGenerator" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:41)
at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:972)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(URLClassLoader.java:237)
at java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:2223)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getInnerClosureClasses(ClosureCleaner.scala:98)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:132)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1893)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:293)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:293)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(MappedDStream.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(MappedDStream.scala:35)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FilteredDStream.compute(FilteredDStream.scala:35)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
```

I dumped the heap of the driver process and seems that 486.2 MB on 512 MB of the available memory is used by an instance of the class *org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryService* tha contains a huge number of instances of the class *org.apache.spark.deploy.history.yarn.HandleSparkEvent*.
I'm trying to figure out how to solve the issue but till now i didn't found a solution.

Could someone help me to sort out the issue?

Thanks

Comment: I think that the issue is related to the Yarn timeline server...

Comment: Were you able to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an exchange of emails with an Hortonworks engineer via the Spark user list (http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/) i solved the issue.
Basically there's a bug that doesn't enable the driver to publish the objects *org.apache.spark.deploy.history.yarn.HandleSparkEvent* to the YARN Timeline Server and hence the number of these messages with the passing of the time grows and grows going to exhaust the memory allocated to the driver.
In order to avoid this issue i deleted the entry *spark.yarn.services* from the file *spark-default.conf*.